# onEdit(e) trigger won't call function automatically in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to calculate some values using my own function (showing dummy function in this question), and I'd like the function to trigger when the user edits a cell in a given range, however even after writing the trigger the only time when the value is calculated again is when I go to the script editor and click *Save*.

My function:

```
function calculate(column) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var column = sheet.getActiveCell().getColumn();

  var values2d = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 15).getValues();
  var values = [].concat.apply([], values2d);

  var testRange2d = sheet.getRange(1, column, 15).getValues();
  var testRange = [].concat.apply([], testRange2d);

  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    if (testRange[i] == true) sum += values[i]
  }

  return sum;
}

function onEdit(e) {
  var activeCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
  if (activeCell.getBackground() === "#e3f5a2") activeCell.setBackground("#ffffff");
  else activeCell.setBackground("#e3f5a2");
  calculate();
}
```

And the sheet:

[image]

The cell besides total is where I call my function. And the value will only be updated either manually or as described earlier, but even when I trigger an event, I have also tried doing other actions in the trigger like changing a random cells value and that worked however.

Comment: custom functions are expected to be deterministic - given an argument, if the argument does not change, then the output does not change. Review the custom function documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions Note that you never use the return value of `calculate` in your `onEdit` trigger, nor do you set the formula for that particular cell to be anything different.

Comment: @tehhowch I also tried using the return value and to set the value of the cell from `onEdit` but that didn't work either, so how would I set the formula?

Comment: Edit your question to include how you have tried to use the return value, and how you have tried to set the formula, from your `onEdit` simple trigger

Comment: @tehhowch I have tried something like `SpreadsheetApp.getRange(16, 2).setValue(calculate());` and I don't know how to set the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might i suggest the following.  This will only occur if a checkbox in column 2 is changed.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  try {
    var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
    if( event.range.getSheet().getName() === "Sheet1" ) {
      if( event.range.getColumn() === 2 ) {
        var values = sheet.getRange(1,1,15,2).getValues();
        var sum = 0;
        for( var i=0; i<values.length; i++ ) {
          if( values[i][1] ) sum += values[i][0];
        }
        sheet.getRange(16,2,1,1).setValue(sum);
        if( event.range.getBackground() === "#e3f5a2" ) 
          event.range.setBackground("#ffffff");
        else
          event.range.setBackground("#e3f5a2");
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: I corrected a mistake in if( event.range.getSheet().getName() === "Sheet1" )